# .mouseover not working right in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

just started learning Javascript and it's pretty hard. But I followed one tutorial and did as he told in his video, but still my result is not what I expected and what he got in his video. I wonder why is that and how I can fix that?

I want to get the box to appear out of nowhere with the text in it and follow the cursor for as long as it is inside the marked territory (**LABEL**- box in HTML).

Here's the code:

```js
$("#rulesInfo").mouseover(function(e) {
 var hovertext = "Info for the block will come here.";
 $("#hoverdiv").text(hovertext).show();
 $("#hoverdiv").css("top", e.clientY+10).css("left", e.clientX+10);
  }).mouseout(function() {
  $("#hoverdiv").hide();
  });
```

```css
#hoverdiv {
display: none;
position: absolute;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #161616;
color: #fff;
border: 1px solid red;
padding: 8px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<FORM>
    <DIV ID="bottom">
    <P>
   <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkedRules" VALUE="yes" REQUIRED /><LABEL FOR="checkedRules" ID="rulesInfo">I have <A HREF="#" TARGET="_blank">read the Rules and Conditions</A> for the trip.</LABEL>
 </P>
  </DIV>
</FORM>

<DIV ID="hoverdiv"></DIV>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="app.js"></SCRIPT>
```

Comment: your label should be surrounding the input. <label><input/></label>

Comment: Looks to be working ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/g3eh1u4s/ Did you load your JS library properly?

Comment: Umm, not sure. Im testing it on my browser and write the codes inside the Notepad++. Should I download some software to make it work more correctly? And my browser is Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m

Comment: You're utilizing jQuery but you're not loading the jQuery libraries at all. You need to include jQuery to use jQuery functions.

Comment: Oh sorry, I do have the libraries they're just at the end of the code and I downloaded them from jQuery.com. I can post whole code if it makes this easier to solve. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would like to do is user the **mousemove** event which fires on every mouse move of the object. **mouseover** only occurs when the mouse first moves over the object.

see here:

```
$("#rulesInfo").mousemove(function(e) {
var hovertext = "Info for the block will come here.";
$("#hoverdiv").text(hovertext).show();
$("#hoverdiv").css("top", e.clientY+10).css("left", e.clientX+10);
  }).mouseout(function() {
  $("#hoverdiv").hide();
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/mzwj26a7/

Comment: Ah thank you so much. Mousemove is the right event. Although the tutorial guy used mouseover. No idea why the code changed so much O_O

Comment: Figured out, he changed mouseover to mousemove, just didn't tell about it in tutorial. Bad tutorialist :D